# Explanation of branching process theory.

Tags: stochastic-processes, branching-rules

Take a look at [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118740653)'s [Chapter-$4$, Page-$159$](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~giacomo/Softwares/R/Dobrow%20-%20Stochastic%20with%20R/ch4.pdf).

It says,

> Assume $0<a_0<1$. If $a_0 = 0$, then the population only grows and $0$ is not in the state space. If $a_0 = 1$, then $Z_n = 0$, for all $n ≥ 1$. We also assume that there is positive probability that an individual gives birth to more than one offspring, that is, $a_0 + a_1 < 1$.

I haven't understood this.

How come population grow if probability = $0$, and $Z_n=0$ if probability=$1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what this is the probability *of*. The definition of $a_0$ is the probability that an individual has zero offspring.

If $a_0=0$, this means it is *impossible* for an individual to have zero offspring. They always have one or more offspring. So the population can never decrease in size, only stay the same or increase.

If $a_0=1$, this means individuals *always* have zero offspring. So the very first individual will die and produce no offspring, and thus you will have $Z_n=0$ for all $n \geq 1$.